# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Partial helper Tag creates issues when Model needs to be loaded from database

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I keep on getting issues when trying to load a partial view that contains a list of items loaded from a database. I have made an example to illustrate my issue:
I have a class 'Product' for which I have created a View 'Index' which shows a list of products. I would like to load that View into another view (the 'HomePage'). I have used the Tag `<Partial name="~/Views/Product/Index.cshtml"/>`. I thought I had to add `for="Product"` or even `model="Product"` but I keep on getting an error (red curly underlining) with error: `An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation`.

Is there a resolution or should I use the old <iframe>-tag instead? I have added the pages below.

THE HOMEPAGE

```
@using PartialViewAlts.Models;


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2>Partial View Tester</h2>        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">   
    <div>
        <h2>Tag Helper Partial method</h2>       
        <partial name="~/Views/Product/Index.cshtml" for="Product"/>  //produces an error     
    </div> 
</div>
```

THE PRODUCTS INDEX PAGE

```
@model IEnumerable<PartialViewAlts.Models.ToDoItem>

<h2>Partial view list of products</h2>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Priority)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsDone)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsDone)</td>                   
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: The Home Controller code has been added

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PartialViewAlts.Data;
using PartialViewAlts.Models;

namespace PartialViewAlts.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {        
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }  

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue lies with the fact you're expecting a IEnumerable for model in the partial while you're stating a for="Product". That is a bit unclear as to what it is at this point

Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2

it specifically states that

> The for attribute assigns a ModelExpression to be evaluated against the current model. A ModelExpression infers the @Model. syntax. For example, for="Product" can be used instead of for="@Model.Product". This default inference behavior is overridden by using the @ symbol to define an inline expression. The for attribute can't be used with the model attribute.

Editing to give an example:

```
public class IndexModel{
public IEnumerable<Product> Products{get;set;}
```

}

The above is an example model you can use. In this case you have IndexModel as the model for your index page while when calling the partial view you will refer as for="@Model.Products"

That way you're passing an IEnumerable inside your partial.

The new error you're getting is because the model you're trying to pass has a mismatch with what the partial method is expecting.

Comment: Hi Giorgos, thank you for your contribution. Should I then use the `model`-attribute instead? That creates another error message 'Product is a type that is not valid in this context'. The IENumerable is a standard when creating an Index View for a listing. Is there a sensible alternative?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, edited my original answer a bit. Let me know if that is not clear enough try a bit better.

Comment: Hi Giorgos, I think I understand the logic, but I cannot get it to work. Feels a little bit stupid of me. I tried adding the IndexModel into the Models section, the Controller section and directly into the cshtml view, but nothing works. I use MVC (not Razor pages). Would that be the issue? Where would you locate the code and how would you call it? Thanks so much for  your help!

Comment: if you're still tackling this issue could you perhaps share some more code? Specifically your index page model?

Comment: I am indeed still struggling and almost giving up and reverting to the iframe-tag. I have added the index-controller code, which is -as you can see- very simple

Comment: Hello again, I notice you don't actually pass a model to the view. You probably want to change this to return view (new index model()) or something. Care to show me the view model you want to pass?

Comment: With the <partial> tag, is it necessary to include a model in the index? The Index View does not involve a model, only the Partial View does. Essentially the Home/Index-page is only a 'naked' page with a partial view. Is this setup not possible? The View is the first view, I included in my question